# how can I find the usable zipping tool on win7 and win10 and zip files using Powershell

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip

I want my script be running on both Win 7 and Win 10 system to generate either zip or 7z files.

On Win10, the `Add-Type` way can be used to generate zip file.

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $destination)
```

However, on Win7 it doesn't work. So I just change the script as:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "D:\$folderName.7z" $source
```

It works however, it's not guaranteed that 7z.exe is installed under `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` for every user.

So I was wondering how can I write a powershell script usable on both Win7 and Win10 without specifying `zip.exe` path.

Comment: Upgrading to PowerShell 5 is your best option if possible. If not, you can code multiple attempts to find a compression method available on the machine. If Add-Type does not work, try looking for 7z.exe in `$Env:ProgramFiles`. If not there, look in `$Env:ProgramFile(x86)` Else...

Answer (score 2):

If upgrading to PowerShell 5 is an option, then it's easy: just use the [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5) cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to check if 7-Zip is installed:

```
$sevenZip = Join-Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::ProgramFiles)) "7-Zip\7z.exe"
if ( -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $sevenZip) ) {
  Write-Error "7-Zip is required." -Category ObjectNotFound
  return  # or exit, if you are in a script
}
# Call it this way:
# & $sevenZip arg1 [arg2 [...]]
```